# ellipse boundary after rotation

Tags: conic-sections

Assume I have this vertical ellipse with a certain major axis $a$ and minor axis $b$.

[image: Not rotated]

If we take the center of the ellipse to be at $(0,0)$, then the top right small red circle will be at $(b,a)$.

Then I rotate it (say by an arbitrary angle $\theta$) about its center:

[image: Rotated]

My question is this: what is the new position of the top right small red circle in this new image after rotation relative to the fixed center? For example at $\theta=90^\circ$ its position will be $(a,b)$.

Comment: you mean ($\sup_{x\in E_\theta} x_1,\sup_{x\in E_\theta} x_2)$, where $E_\theta= R_\theta (E)$?

Comment: Yes! Is there any mathematical expression saying exactly how that point is related to $a$, $q$ (axis ratio) and $\theta$? For example: at $\theta=90$degrees that point will be on (a,b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
r(t)=(a\,\cos (t), b\, \sin(t))              
$$
After rotation,
$$
r_2(t)=R_\theta.r(t)= (a\,cos(t)\cos(\theta)+b\sin(t)\sin(\theta),-a\,cos(t)\sin(\theta)+b\sin(t)\cos(\theta))
$$
So you need to find the maximum of $ a\,cos(t)\cos(\theta)+b\sin(t)\sin(\theta)$ and $-a\,cos(t)\sin(\theta)+b\sin(t)\cos(\theta)$.

Can you do it?

Comment: I don't understand what $t$ is?

Comment: $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and $r(t)$ is a parametrization of the ellipse.

Comment: Do you have some knowledge of calculus?

Comment: So there is no exact (analytic) answer to this other than testing the whole range of $0\leq t\leq2\pi$? Fortunately I know how to find the maximum of this function ;-). Thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: You are welcome. There is an exact analytic solution but is bit complicated.

Comment: I tried finding the analytic answer, thanks again for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Following Pocho la pantera's explanation, I just thought to extend it. We know that for the rotated ellipse:

$$
x=acos(t)cos(\theta)+bsin(t)sin(\theta)
$$

Taking the derivative and setting it to zero we find the $t$ that gives the extremuems of x:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=-asin(t)cos(\theta)+bcos(t)sin(\theta)=0
$$

$$
asin(t)cos(\theta)=bcos(t)sin(\theta)
$$
$$
tan(t)=\frac{b}{a}tan(\theta)
$$

Following the same steps for $y$ we find the $t$ that gives the maximum $y$:

$$
y=-acos(t)sin(\theta) + bsin(t)cos(\theta)
$$

$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=asin(t)sin(\theta)+bcos(t)cos(\theta)=0
$$

$$
asin(t)sin(\theta)=-bcos(t)cos(\theta)
$$

$$
tan(t)=-\frac{b}{a}cot(\theta)
$$